# Switching letters in a string and recieving an index out of range error in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a program that will input a sentence, and then two letters, and then switch all instances of those letters and then print out the switched sentence. For instance, they could input

```
I like to eat bananas
```

and then “e” and “a,” and my program would print

```
I lika to aet benenes
```

Here is my code, but at the end it prints out String Index out of line. 
Any ideas how to fix this?

```
System.out.println("Write something awesome.");
String input1 = Keyboard.readString();
System.out.println("Pick a letter from that awesome sentence.");
char letter1 = Keyboard.readChar();
System.out.println("Pick another letter from that awesome sentence.");
char letter2 = Keyboard.readChar();

double let1 = (input1.length());
int let1Next = (int) let1;
double let2 = (input1.length());
int let2Next = (int) let2;

String newUserImput = input1.replace(input1.charAt(let1Next),
        input1.charAt(let2Next));
System.out.println(newUserImput);
```

Comment: You program doesn't make sense (based on what it's you want to achieve).  You are ignoring `letter1` and `letter2` and instead are trying to replace the same character, a character I might add, that doesn't exist...

Comment: OP, If any of these answers were helpful, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

The method `replace` will replace all chars in the string

So what you want is

```
String new1 = input1.replace (letter1, letter2);
String new2 = input1.replace (letter2, letter1);
```

Then iterate over the original string to see what is different in `new1` and `new2`.

Comment: It is more complex, because OP don't want to replace only `letter1` with `letter2` but also `letter2` with `letter1`.

Answer (score 0):

Without a stack trace, I have to guess the exception is on this line.

```
String newUserImput = input1.replace(input1.charAt(let1Next),
        input1.charAt(let2Next));
```

What does input1.charAt(let1Next) resolve to?

```
double let1 = (input1.length());
int let1Next = (int) let1;
double let2 = (input1.length());
int let2Next = (int) let2;
```

This can't really be what you mean.

let1Next will represent the end of the array + 1 as will let2Next.

Therefore, there are 2 major bugs here:

1. You are replacing all occurrences of a given character with itself.
2. The letter you are picking is beyond the end of the string.  Remember, string indexes (such as the input to String.charAt) are 0-based, so the they range from 0 through (length - 1).  By specifying input1.length, you are asking for the character **after** the last character of the string, hence the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over array that contains all characters of user sentence (you can get such array using `toCharArray` method invoked on `input1`) and if you find `letter1` replace it with `letter2` and vice-versa.
After that you can create new string based on updated array with `new String(arrayOfCharacters)`.

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
char[] cs = input1.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
    char c = cs[i];
    if (letter1 == c) {
        cs[i] = letter2;
    } else if (letter2 == c) {
        cs[i] = letter1;
    }
}

String newUserImput = new String(cs);
```

Comment: Why are you treating letter1 and letter2 as if they were Strings and not chars?

Comment: ys i have corrected it. when i implement it i was treat letter1 and letter2 as string. sorry. thanks for information.

Comment: While this code may (or may not) solve the OP's problem, the code-only answer is likely to get deleted without some text to explain how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using char array-

```
char letter1 = 'a';
char letter2 = 'e';
String s = "I like to eat bananas";
char[] chrs = s.toCharArray();
int n = chrs.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (chrs[i] == letter1) {//if array contains letter1 at intdex i
        chrs[i] = letter2; //replace with letter 2
    } else if (chrs[i] == letter2) { //if array contains letter2 at intdex i
        chrs[i] = letter1;//replace with letter 1
    }    
}

String swapedString = new String(chrs);
System.out.println(swapedString );
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting String index out of line because you tried to access characters outside of the string (valid range is from 0 to length-1). And even if you used length-1, your code will not do what you want. What you really need is to have two dummy placeholders (I assume your string will never contain '#' or '$') replacing 'a' and 'e' and then swap 'a' and 'e' with the dummy placeholders. The code follows:

```
System.out.println("Write something awesome.");
String input1 = "I like to eat bananas";//Keyboard.readString();
System.out.println("Pick a letter from that awesome sentence.");
char letter1 = 'e';
System.out.println("Pick another letter from that awesome sentence.");
char letter2 = 'a';

// dummy placeholders
char letter3 = '#';
char letter4 = '$';

String newUserImput = input1.replace (letter1, letter3);
newUserImput = newUserImput.replace (letter2, letter4);
newUserImput = newUserImput.replace (letter3, letter2);
newUserImput = newUserImput.replace (letter4, letter1);

System.out.println(newUserImput);
```

Comment: How can you make an assumption that the user entered string will not contain '#' or '$' as they are on the keyboard

Comment: This is an illustrative example. You can use anything from the ascii table which is not on the keyboard, as a dummy placeholder. With a careful implementation, you don't even need two placeholders.